# Swift 3 "updateChildValues" method fails with: Invalid key in object. Keys must be non-empty and cannot contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update Firebase Database with email as value.
But Swift 3 "updateChildValues" method fails with an error: `Invalid key in object. Keys must be non-empty and cannot contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''`
The code is:

```
    let key = emailQueueRef.childByAutoId()
    if user.email != nil {
        inviteUpdate["\(key)"] = user.email!
    }
    emailQueueRef.updateChildValues(inviteUpdate)
```

Possibly, it fail because of dots in email. In other hand, encoding it into Base64 didn't fix it. 
In the same time using "setValue" method works:

```
    emailQueueRef.childByAutoId().setValue(user.email!)
```

But this approach is not quite good for me as I make it with several paths simultaneously.
I didn't find anything about that case in Firebase guides and docs
Is it a Firebase bug, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Changed email with string value: "dummy". And it didn't worked anyway. Only when using "key" as reference, it works.  But this contradicts firebase guides and docs. I assume it's a bug.

Comment: It isn't. You're using the email address as the key in the dictionary, which becomes a key in the database. And keys can't contain `.` characters. See my updated answer and comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the inviteUpdate string.

The string contains illegal characters but it's not the period . causing the problem. It's the ["(key)"] portion.

the var *key* is a Firebase DatabaseReference

The key you are trying to write to Firebase looks like this

```
["https://your_app.firebaseio.com/email_node/-KorK9Io5Y2XejgLInvj": "dude@someemail.com"]
```

It's not clear from the question what the actual Firebase structure should be but I think what you want is this

```
let key = emailQueueRef.childByAutoId()
if user.email != nil {
    inviteUpdate[key.key] = user.email!  //note key.key
}

emailQueueRef.updateChildValues(inviteUpdate)
```

which then writes this to Firebase

```
"-KorOLfUa9HvgDIcpIyg": "dude@thing.com"
```

I am going to urge you to not use email addresses as keys as it can lead to a lot of work later on.

For example, if a user changes their email address. You then need to totally delete the user node that uses it as a key, and re-write it. At the same time, anywhere else that references that key will also have to be changed.

It's usually much better to include the email as a child node

```
uid_0
  email: "dude@someemail.com"
```

and then other areas can simply refer to uid_0.

Answer (score 1):

After some attempt I've found my main error. I got `DatabaseReference` with `childByAutoId()` and I just missed one additional step in the guide, to get the key itself.
The resulting code is:

```
    let keyRef = emailQueueRef.childByAutoId()
    let key = keyRef.key
    if user.email != nil {
        inviteUpdate[key] = user.email!
    }
    emailQueueRef.updateChildValues(inviteUpdate)
```

Finally that helped.